# Load Selectedrow of datagrid to label

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

I am trying to load mysql data to label when I select a row in gridview.

[image]

here is my class that gets the selected row value and bind it to label.

```
 private void LoadOrders()
 {
     con.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select quo_product,quo_address
                            FROM JobQuotations
                            WHERE quotationId = @id
                            AND quo_product = @product",con);

     //1st row 2nd column                 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",GridView1.SelectedIndex.ToString());

     //1st row 3rd column 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product",GridView1.SelectedIndex.ToString());

     if(rdr.HasRows)
     {
         while(rdr.Read())
         {
             lblProductName.Text = rdr["quo_product"].ToString();
             lblAddress.Text = rdr["quo_Address"].ToString();
         }
     }
     con.Close();
 }
```

I know I lack some codes inside of my **if** statement because I don't know how to get the selected rows value on it.What will I input inside my **cmd.Parameter** in order to get the **selectedRow** values?

Comment: You can get selected row value using  'OnSelectedIndexChanged' event  inside gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it doesn't work let me know the issues and ill see what i can change to make it work, i haven't done it with 2 different cell names before. Can you update the image at the top with the datagridview to have the column names of the datagridview you are using please.

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid1.SelectedRows)
            {
                string quo_product = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                //string quo_Address = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            }
            lblProductName.Text = quo_product;
            //lblAddress.Text = quo_Address;
        }
```

**UPDATE**

This question is fixed due to a question asked later on by rai nalasa ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180305/getting-null-on-data-grid-view?noredirect=1#comment61895339_37180305))

Comment: that is commented out because it wont work with 2, in that way so try it with that for now and then we can focus on getting the second one to work

Comment: Wait let me try it for a sec.

Comment: dude the code you gave me on my previous question worked already.

Comment: Oh, so this question is fixed because of the last question?

Comment: Yeah.I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColumnName"].Value` Or `GridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[index or column name]`

Comment: I have to put `loadOrders` class inside the `OnSelectedIndexChange` right?

Comment: You could use anywhere just need to check if any row selected

Comment: If you want to change the label each time you change selected row, then yes, you need it in OnSelectedIndexChange event. Remember to check if any row is selected, if the values are not null and all those things. ;)

Comment: You wan to call LoadOrders() on row click ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx) it could be same that you want.

Comment: Yes, sorry it will not work on asp. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)