# Getting null on data grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I followed this guide and modified some of its code for my own
for retrieving a selectedrow for datagridview.

This is the [guide](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx).It's not that close to my problem thought as it doesn't use any sql query.

I'm using s **Select** query which needed a value from datagridview so when I triggered the button event,It gives me the value on my label.

here is the datagridview

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT quotationID,quo_product
                             FROM JobQuotations
                             WHERE quo_custname = @custname", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname",lblLoginName.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

and This is my class for selecting a row:

```
 private void LoadOrders()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select quo_product,quo_address
                            FROM JobQuotations
                            WHERE quotationId = @id
                            AND quo_product = @product",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);

        if(rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                lblProductName.Text = rdr["quo_product"].ToString();
                lblAddress.Text = rdr["quo_Address"].ToString();
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

This line of code that is giving me error:

```
 `if(rdr.HasRows)`
```

*An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MejShop.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Comment: The problem occurs in in the `MejShop` dll library. What is that library? Which line in the code calls something from that library?

Comment: wait I'm going to update my question.

Comment: is that a datagridview?, not a datagrid?

Comment: @Brendon It is a gridview.

Comment: ok, have you debugged the program to see what it is doing?

Comment: I did.This was my latest progress.

Comment: try removing the rdr.HasRows if statement and just put the while(rdr.Read()), as the while will only run if there has been something selected from the database... not sure how much this will change but then debug it again and see where it crashes now

Comment: also where is your datareader?

Comment: @Brendon Do I have to put anything inside `Page_load` or `!isPostBack`?This two alse gives me error

Comment: Where is your datareader, because my theory is that is the issue?

Comment: @rainalasa can i see your page_load and/or where you use !isPostBack

Comment: ohhh damn.`rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` above the `while` clause right?

Comment: @rainalasa it isnt there, no?

Comment: dude you are right.I feel so dumb right now.Can I please give you credit?

Comment: no problem, i have made and answer, i think that was what you said fixed it

Comment: I did. I've been solving this for hours.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and add the `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` above the while loop.